# Automatically Display POST data Django

Tags: python, django, rest, post, django-views

**Goal:**

- Display POST data on Django-based website as it is received via webhooks from Github
- If possible, to continually append new events one after the other on the website

**Where I'm at:**

- I have the github POST data, I can print it on the terminal, but cannot display on my html page.
- Currently a beginner with Django but any advice would be much appreciated!

Here's a peak at my **views.py**:

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        event = request.META['HTTP_X_GITHUB_EVENT']
        body = json.loads(request.body)[event]

        context = {
            'event': event,
            'body': body,
        }
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Here is my **home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h3><b>fudge</b></h3>
    {% if event %}
        <p>Event: {{ event }}</p>
        <p>Body: {{ body }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Ideally, I'd like to re-render my home.html page as soon as a POST is received, but don't know how to keep it persistent. As for my urls.py, I only have ^$, views.home, name='home'. Let me know if you'd like to see anything else!